# Group by up to a certain date in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a date range and some counts, I want to aggregate per date and for all the date up to a certain point, using only spark.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-10-20', end='2018-11-10', freq='D').astype('str')
df = pd.Series(dates)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df, StringType())
df = df.withColumn('users', (F.randn(1)*10).astype(IntegerType()))
```

Here is a sample of what the dataframe looks like:

```
+----------+-----+
|     value|users|
+----------+-----+
|2018-10-20|  -10|
|2018-10-21|    2|
|2018-10-22|    6|
|2018-10-23|    2|
```

And this is a sample of the expected output:

```
    all_users  daily       dates
0           1      1  2018-10-20
1           2      1  2018-10-21
2           3      1  2018-10-22
3           4      1  2018-10-23
```

My solution to get the previous output for the moment is a workaround with an external for loop and pandas but this is obviously not scalable, here is my current solution:

```
daily_users = []
all_users = []

for d in dates:
    daily_users.append(df.where(F.col('value') == d).count())
    all_users.append(df.where(F.col('value') <= d).count())

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'dates':dates.values,'daily':daily_users,'all_users':all_users})
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You are right I added df1 as an example desired output, ideally that would be a spark dataframe

Comment: Running count ?

Comment: First off include a reproducible example, this just seems incomplete. As far the solution, looking at the incomplete stuff, why can't you use a filter first then groupBy

Comment: can you please add sample and expected output?

Comment: I updated the question with toy output and a better explanation